# How to make an app to app communication over network from one device to another in Android?

Tags: android, mobile

I want to create an Android app that could communicate itself over network. What I want is to send a message from an app to the same app in another device (like how a messenger app communicates with each other). How do I do this?.I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,
-Parash-

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways and modes of communincation avaiable nowadays, please specify your requirements more precisely. As per messenger communications, devices dont directly interact with each other there is a chat server by which both applications/phones interact. You also make your own. but you need to own a chat server to do so.

If you use Bluetooth or NFC as mode of communications, devices need to be in range of each other.

Third way is to have sms communication, but it involves operator cost to send sms.

Comment: Hi,
   Thanks for your reply. This is what I want to implement:

1. App on device A sends a request to app on device B to initiate something. 

2. App on device B gets the request and does something as per the request.

How do I do this?Please help.

Thanks,
-Parash-